# Creating multiple records with some repeated values using a form

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access, vba

I have been trying to figure this situation out for a few days and was hoping someone here could help me out.

I want to create a form that inserts multiple records at a time.

However all the records have some data that will be repeated.

For example Employee ID, Supervisor ID, and Researcher ID will be repeated along with the dates of each persons involvement.

The data that will differ would be the inventory items. (location, item number, condition, count, etc etc.

So for every new entry within the inventory information, i would like to include the repeated information when being copied over to the table.

The way i envision this is having some sort of sub form for the multiple data entries. Then, maybe having unbound text boxes on the header of the main page that keeps the values the same and lastly having a footer showing the previous records entered. I have limited VB coding skills. However i can pick things up quickly and debug if needed.

If you need more clarification please dont hesitate to ask.

Comment: If those values are repeated for all the related records, then they should be in a parent record (with a unique ID) , with the changing items stored in a child table related back to the parent record.

Comment: with that being said would the parent table have all the field names including a primary key (with autonumber) where as the child table would only consist of the changing values?

Comment: Lets call the parent table Employees - and the EmployeeID is unique. Your Child table we will call Inventory. Each item will have a unique InventoryID, and will also have the EmployeeID  that the inventory was issued to (it's called a foreign key). You only need the employeeID as the other data (supervisor etc) can be pulled in from the employee table. Does that make sense?

Comment: What is the recordsource of the parent and subform? Do these IDs appear on the parent form?

Comment: Minty, I have created the parent and child relationship. With regards to the type of form which would you recommend being used? Parfait, I have not created a record source to the parent and subform as of yet.

Comment: A parent sub form would work well if the data entry was small quantities, You could also simply use a continuous form with suitable combo's to select the employees and equipment types.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the feedback. I ended up creating 2 tables with two forms. the main form is the parent with textboxes that are bounded to the subform. Im not sure how to explain it but thanks to the input here i made it work. Thank you again.